# ONE-MANY relationship how to write in sql loader script

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have 2 tables like below

```
tab1
Dept_no   Deptname
1         IT
2         ADMIN

tab2
Emp_no   Emp_name   Deptno
1        AAA         1
2        BBB         1
3        ccc         2
```

I want to write SQL Loader script

Comment: What does it exactly mean? SQL*Loader is utility which loads data into tables. You have tables. Where's data you'd want to load? Control file deeply depends on input file format.

Comment: The Oracle documentation for SQL\*Loader is online, comprehensive and free. [Find it here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144.htm#SUTIL3311). If you have a **specific problem** please post the details, including input file structure, sample data, what code you have written, error messages and so on.

Comment: I want script total script